# how to log the ssh public key's label to auth.log

Tags: logging, sshd

I was wondering if there was a way to log the label of an ssh public key to auth.log.

I've given www-data only sftp access to the web directory, and use ssh keys to authorize a trusted user on my development server.

I want to be able to see which trusted user logged in based off their public key label in auth.log. is there any way to do this without compromising security?

Comment: Try with `LogLevel DEBUG3` in `sshd_config`.

Comment: It didn't produce my desired results, but at the least it was able to give me the matching key's line number in the authorized_keys file. it looks like I only need to set LogLevel to DEBUG1 to capture this piece of information. Thank you for the advice @heemayl